# Only does two files instead of 100

Tags: vb.net, file, system.io.file

**Basically I have this file creator program which is helping me to make a bunch of files and for some reason, it only does 2 instead of 100 files specified.**
*Code:*

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Main

    Dim CURRENT_NUM As Integer
    Dim CONTENT_STRING As String
    Dim PATH_STRING As String
    Dim FROM_NUM As Integer
    Dim TO_NUM As Integer

    Public Sub SetupVar()
        Try
            CONTENT_STRING = tbContent.Text
            PATH_STRING = tbPath.Text
            FROM_NUM = Integer.Parse(tbFrom.Text)
            TO_NUM = Integer.Parse(tbTo.Text)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Make()
        tmrMake.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnMake_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMake.Click
        SetupVar()
        Make()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnQuit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnQuit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmrMake_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrMake.Tick
        'disable quit
        'and control box
        Me.ControlBox = False
        btnQuit.Enabled = False
        CURRENT_NUM = FROM_NUM
        CURRENT_NUM = CURRENT_NUM + 1
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(PATH_STRING & CURRENT_NUM & ".txt")
            sw.Write(CONTENT_STRING)
        End Using
        If CURRENT_NUM = TO_NUM Then
            btnQuit.Enabled = True
            Me.ControlBox = True
            tmrMake.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

*The result is c1 and c2 in the folder. Instead of 1-100 As i specified in the two tb.*

Comment: What is the interval on your timer?

Comment: Tried 100 and 1000 now 1000

Comment: You are resetting CURRENT_NUM to FROM_NUM + 1 in every Timer Tick. You need to move `CURRENT_NUM = FROM_NUM` out of the Timer Tick hander and put to somewhere where it will only be executed once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move some of your code around and then you should be good.  See the code below...

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Main

    Dim CURRENT_NUM As Integer
    Dim CONTENT_STRING As String
    Dim PATH_STRING As String
    Dim FROM_NUM As Integer
    Dim TO_NUM As Integer

    Public Sub SetupVar()
        Try
            CONTENT_STRING = tbContent.Text
            PATH_STRING = tbPath.Text
            FROM_NUM = Integer.Parse(tbFrom.Text)
            TO_NUM = Integer.Parse(tbTo.Text)

            ' Moved code from tmrMake_Tick to here
            'disable quit
            'and control box
            Me.ControlBox = False
            btnQuit.Enabled = False
            CURRENT_NUM = FROM_NUM
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Make()
        tmrMake.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnMake_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMake.Click
        SetupVar()
        Make()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnQuit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnQuit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmrMake_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrMake.Tick
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(PATH_STRING & CURRENT_NUM & ".txt")
            sw.Write(CONTENT_STRING)
        End Using

        ' Increment your CURRENT_NUM after you've written the file
        CURRENT_NUM = CURRENT_NUM + 1
        If CURRENT_NUM = TO_NUM Then
            btnQuit.Enabled = True
            Me.ControlBox = True
            tmrMake.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: actually Blackwood answered it so all regards to him